# Drupal views_embed_view sorting

Tags: php, drupal

I have a Drupal 7 module which includes a database query that gives me a list of jobs id's in a specific order based on calculated distance from a user-inputted location (nearest first, furthest last).

I then pass the job id's to views_embed_view as arguments with a contextual filter on the view. This then displays a list of jobs to the user.

However, whilst there is no sorting specified within the view, the order gets changed automatically. e.g. if the order of the records passed to views_embed_view is 10,52,22 it displays in the following order: 10,22,52 i.e. it gets ordered numerically ascending.

Any ideas on how to get views_embed_view to stop re-sorting my results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I'd post how I solved it in case anyone encounters this issue in future:

A Drupal module called **Views Arguments Extras** includes a sort handler which allows for the order of items to be based on their order in a multi-value argument:

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_arguments_extras

Many thanks to the contributors of this module.